# Handling subfolders in embedded Google Drive folders within Google Sites

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sites

I'm using Google Sites to build a website that is largely a front-end for Google Drive folders. I'd like the site to embed some of these folders, but I'm unhappy with the way Google Sites seems to handle sub-folders: whether I set up the drive folder as an iframe or with the built-in gadget, subfolders will open up a new tab, rather than display the contents of the subfolder within the iframe.

Furthermore, this new tab will always display the contents of this subfolder in grid view, while list view would make much more sense for the kind of data involved. (And it opens up the new folder as a grid, even if the gadget is set to display folder contents as a list). Any thoughts on how to change either of these?